# 'Order' entity bean

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, ejb-2.x, cmp

My database has a table name `Order`. When I create a new CMP Entity bean, NetBeans 6.9.1 automatically generated a bean with 3 classes name:

- `Order1.java`
- `Order1Local.java`
- `Order1LocalHome.java`

I tried to rename those 3 classes to `Order` without the 1. I've already edit the `ejb-jar.xml` file. However, I got this error when deploying the project:

> JDO7704: This error (In DatabaseGenerator, failed to get 'relClassName' for 'order') should not occur

I also tried the name `OrderBean` but it only works with `Order1`. What should I do to rename my entity bean to `Order`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Order` is a reserved word in some dbms (used in `order by` expressions). Maybe that is the reason why Netbeans adds the 1. You should name your table different.

Just found this useful tool: [SQL Reserved Words Checker](http://www.petefreitag.com/tools/sql_reserved_words_checker/). It says that Order is not reserved in ISO/ANSI,SQL99 but in dbms like DB2 or Oracle.

Comment: Thanks, but it's ok for the table. It just does not work for the entity bean

Comment: @Heiko Ok... too far out of the window ;-)